# Sending all input fields with jquery .post()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have collected the values of all input field into an array as follows:

```
 $( ".formbox" ) . each( function(id,elem){
    form_fields[ "input-" + $( elem ) . attr( "id" )  ] = $( elem ) . val( ); 
   });

 $.log( "Collected:", form_fields );
```

This does work, and then I try passing the array using post

```
 $.post(
    "server.php", 
    {
        fields: form_fields
    },
    function(ret) {

       if (!ret.success )
         alert ( "Error! Reload please!" );
       else
       {
       }
    }, 
    'json'
  );
```

However while retrieving, Firebug indicates that the fields are empty

As I understood I need to serialize the array or not use it at all. But what could I use instead?

Please tell what is it that I am doing wrong?

---------- added ----------
...I just found this

```
 form_fields = {};
```

:)

I don't understand how but that solved the problem
Please tell me what the difference is between an Array and {}? What does {} in JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is used for creating objects and `[]` is used for arrays to indicate indexes. The difference is that.

Sample code:

```
var obj = {name:"Captain",last_name:"Caveman",run:function(speed){//run;}}

//equivalent to 

var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Captain";
obj.last_name = "caveman";
obj.run = function(speed){
  //run;
}
```

I've just created a new object on-the-fly with `{}` follow the code below to call its members

```
document.write(obj.name); 
document.write(obj.run("fast"));
```

But arrays are more simple than an object.

**JSON:** Javascript Object Notation

More about JSON: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

More about Arrays: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 2):

I can only recommend the [JQuery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started). It takes care of all this mess and even supports a transparent file upload mode. (Because normally you cant upload files using AJAX.)

Comment: Your have true, but am trying make this more from scratch & with minimal using of plugins & so on. Cause this make application slower.

Comment: I think the speed loss is actually negligible. The download is only an few k, less than most pictures. And the computational overhead is also really small.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var fields = {};
$('.formbox input').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    fields['input-' + $this.attr('name')] = $this.val(); 
});

$.log( "Collected:", fields );


$.post("server.php", fields, function(ret) {
   if (!ret.success)
     alert ( "Error! Reload please!" );
   else{
   }
}, 'json');
```

`form_fields = {};` means assign an empty Object to `form_fields`. `{}` is used to denote objects, whereas `[]` is used to denote arrays.